# How to get Facebook posts of same type grouped into one, separately?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API to get all the posts on my own timeline.
There is a problem. Because it was my birthday yesterday and all of the posts were done on my profile by others(my friends), these posts are shown as clubbed into one.

This is the response I get in one of the posts when I make an API call at `/v2.1/me/feed`

`189 friends posted on your timeline for your birthday.`

But I want to read(get) the posts separately. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook aggregates all your friend birthday posts in a single post. Once the posts are aggregated there is no way to retrieve the individual post as they don't longer exist.